# Golang - Store / Retrieve decimal from MySQL

Tags: mysql, go

I am using the gin gonic framework and have built a JSON API.

I have a new end point I want to make but one of the values is a decimal. I created the following struct:

```
type AcceptedTerms struct {
    Id          int64           
    FirstName   string          
    LastName    string                    
    Fee         ***DECIMAL***
    Date        *time.Time
}
```

My controller snippets of code:

```
    query = "SELECT " +
            "AcceptedTerms.* " +
            "FROM AcceptedTerms " +
            "ORDER BY " + sort_by + " " + order_by +
            " LIMIT " + limit2 +
            " OFFSET " + offset2`
```

`_, err := dbmap.Select(&response.AcceptedTerms, query)`

What should I set the type to be for decimal? I want the user to be able to post decimals e.g. 10.44 or 12.00 etc rather than "10.44" or "12.00". I also want the value to be returned as above rather than as a string.

**Update**

I tried to do this to my Struct but it's still not displaying as 2 decimal places

```
type AcceptedTerms struct {
    Id          int64
    FirstName   string
    LastName    string
    Fee         Number
    Date        *time.Time
}

type Number float64

func (n Number) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", n)), nil
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does `float32` pose any problems? Since MySQL uses 32 bits to store `DECIMAL`, `float32` should be good enough.

Comment: It works, but 4.10 would display as 4.1 and 4.00 would display as 4 which is not what I want.

Comment: c.JSON(httpcode, gin.H{"meta": s, "data": response.AcceptedTerms})

Comment: That is the default behavior of `encoding/json` package. It represents numbers like 4.00 as 4 and 4.10 as 4.1 in the marshalled output.

Comment: Is there anyway to stop this as this is a fee so currency, therefore it should display as 4.00 and 4.10?

Comment: While displaying, the client can format the value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For scanning MySQL values to Go vars the good practice is to use sql.Null... types. Especially when column is nullable.

For decimals it can be sql.NullFloat64:

```
// ...
var dec sql.NullFloat64
row.Scan(&dec)
// dec.Valid - bool
// dec.Float64 - float64
```