# How can I scan decimal value?

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a get function that I pass an Id.

I have a column called "Salary" that i defined as DECIMAL (13,2)

In Go i try to define this property in struct in int, int68, big.Rat but when i make a scan i receive:

> 2019/07/13 00:05:25 sql: Scan error on column index 6, name "Salary":
> unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *big.Rat

My get function:

```
func (app *App) getFuncionary(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    Id, ok := vars["Id"]
    if !ok {
        log.Println("No one id found")
    }

    dbdata := &Funcionary{}
    err := app.Database.QueryRow("SELECT Id,Data,xx,xxy,xxxx,xxxxx,Salario,xxxxxx FROM `funcionarys` WHERE Id = ?", Id).Scan(&dbdata.Id, &dbdata.Data, &xx, &xxy, &xxxx, &dbdata.xxxxx, &dbdata.Salario, &dbdata.xxxxxx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("You fetched a thing!")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(dbdata); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

My database connection string don't have parsetime:

```
connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s?charset=utf8mb4&collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci&multiStatements=true", user, password, serverName, dbName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`NullFloat64`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullFloat64) type (a float64 that may be null), as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37177092/6309)

```
var dec sql.NullFloat64
row.Scan(&dec)
```